# Creating directory on external sd card. (write access error)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-external-storage

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uzpy3qdYXmE to get permission for writing and reading to a external SD card using the path: /storage/XXXX-XXXX/. But even though the code seems to be happy to give me the permissions, I still get access denied error's when writing to the SD card (when creating a Directory for example).

This is happens on Android 7.0 (Custom rom).

Just to make things more difficult, the creating of a directory happens within a seperate made library that is supposed to run cross-platform. I use compilation symbols to compile the library for specific platforms.

The app itself is a WebView app which interfaces with the code in the library via a websocket server initiated by the library.

My initial idea was to request all the needed permissions within the MainActivity and that would've been it. But apparently I am missing something.

Here is the error message:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/09F6-DC14/Test" is denied.
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x0004b] in <fd78fee11d3a4b2b99a184d3a0faf63e>:0 
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00075] in <fd78fee11d3a4b2b99a184d3a0faf63e>:0 
at Library.Handlers.DirectoryHandler.CreateDirectory (System.String path, System.String name) [0x000db] in
```

Here is my manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     package="TestApp.TestApp" android:versionCode="1"     android:versionName="0.0.1 Preview Version -WIP"     android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="TestApp" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"></application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the AssemblyInfo.cs:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Android.App;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("TestApp")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("TestApp")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2018")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]


[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)]
```

Here is the code that requests the permissions (changed from the code used in the above mentioned tutorial):

MainActivity.cs:

```cs
    readonly string[] PermissionsGroupExternalStorage=
    {
                //TODO add more permissions
                Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage,
                Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage
    };


    async Task GetPermissionsAsync()
    {
        const string permissionRead = Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage;
        const string permissionWrite = Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage;

        if  ((CheckSelfPermission(permissionRead) == (int)Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted) && (CheckSelfPermission(permissionWrite) == (int)Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted))
        {
            //TODO change the message to show the permissions name
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Storage permissions granted.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            return;
        } else 
        {

            Toast.MakeText(this, "Storage permissions not granted.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            //set alert for executing the task
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.SetTitle("Storage Permissions Needed");
            alert.SetMessage("The application need special permissions to read and write to (external) storage devices to continue");
            alert.SetPositiveButton("Request Permissions", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                RequestPermissions(PermissionsGroupExternalStorage, RequestLocationId);
            });

            alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Cancelled!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            });

            Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
            dialog.Show();


        }

        RequestPermissions(PermissionsGroupExternalStorage, RequestLocationId);

        return;
    }
```

And then I just try to create a directory (within the crossplatform(ish) library) with the following code:

DirectoryHandler Class in my library:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("/storage/09F6-DC14/Test")
```

Obviously there are improvements that could be done to the code, but I want to get it to work first...

The toast returns "Storage permission granted" so I believe that I do have the permissions set correctly, that is what is stopping me from solving this, if this isn't due to permissions... what else could block me from accessing my external storage?

Is it possible that I actually have to request permission every time that I try to write/read from/to a external storage device? It seems a bit of hack doing it that way.

Comment: What does `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath` give you?

Comment: I'd check on your Android device in settings > apps > your app > app permissions to make sure the permission is indeed enabled. Also, what is your Android apps Target Framework currently set to?

Comment: @Nick The toggle switch for storage is set to "on" (?), so the permission is set. & target set to sdk 24 (android 7.0);

Comment: @Orkhan Alikhanov: I tested the following: ExternalStorageState, ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath & GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath), with the following result in order: "mounted, /storage/emulated/0,  /storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0") so apparently it does see something being mounted, might just be the internal storage, but no trace of my sd card.

Comment: If I check (within MainActivity.cs with GetExternalFilesDirs(null)[1] I get the directory for my app on my sd card, but this can only be done within MainActivity, I need the context, which I dont (want) to pass to the library as the class that write files sits deeply within the library itself, and I dont want the ugliness that comes with passing through contexts). + This is probably the only directory where I am allowed to write even without permission as it's the locally owned directory for app owned files.

Comment: Proven by the fact that I can in fact create and write to the /storage/09F6-DC14/Android/TestApp.TestApp/files/NewlyCreatedDirectory, but when I try to create a directory at /storage/09F6-DC14/NewDirectory and try to write to it, it crashes with the same System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: For your path, I'd try changing it to `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/Test");` if it still doesn't like external then I'd try internal as a test `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);` and see if you get the same results.